# get objects which adoes not contain a certain key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a section in which user can filter different data on drop-down select ,

I have an array of data as follows.

```
const data = [
    {
        name: 'Trump',
        country: 'USA',
        age: 70,
        IQ: 140,
    },
    {
        name: 'ID Amini',
        country: 'Uganda',
        age: 50,
    },
    {
        name: 'Kenyatta',
        country: 'Kenya',
        age: 60,
        
    },
    {
        name: 'Obama',
        country: 'USA',
        age: 45,
        IQ: 141
        
    }
]
```

**My aim is also to be able to get all objects which do not contain IQ as you can see in the above array there are objects which do not contain IQ.**

Live demo : [demo](https://codepen.io/makumba/pen/PoeMjoY)

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
let filter = ['empty']; // passed dynamically u can pass eg Obama, kenyata etc etc
let filterTyped ='IQ' // passed dynamically als here u can pass name, country etc etc

let filtredData = filter.forEach((item) =>{
    let dataFilter = data.find((element) =>{
        //return all objects which does not contain IQ if Item is empyt
        if(item === 'empty'){
            return element[filterTyped] ==undefined;
        }
        // return found object
        return element[filterTyped] ==item;
    })

    console.log('Filtred', dataFilter)
    if(!dataFilter) return;
})
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: to get multiple results, use `data.filter()` instead of `data.find()`

Comment: @GrafiCode I want to able to get single object and at the same time to be able to get all objects which does not contain a certain key that is why I used find

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to achieve this:

1. Check with the `hasOwnProperty` method:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Trump', country: 'USA', age: 70, IQ: 140 },
  { name: 'ID Amini', country: 'Uganda', age: 50 },
  { name: 'Kenyatta', country: 'Kenya', age: 60 },
  { name: 'Obama', country: 'USA', age: 45, IQ: 141 }
];

const filtered = data.filter((e) => !e.hasOwnProperty('IQ'));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

2. Check with destructuring:

Careful with using just `IQ` and `!IQ` as a return value, because falsy values like `0` will be false, even though that is a valid value for a field that holds a numeric value.

```js
const isNumeric = (n) => !isNaN(n - parseFloat(n));

const data = [
  { name: 'Trump', country: 'USA', age: 70, IQ: 150 },
  { name: 'ID Amini', country: 'Uganda', age: 50 },
  { name: 'Kenyatta', country: 'Kenya', age: 60 },
  { name: 'Obama', country: 'USA', age: 45, IQ: 141 },
  { name: 'Foobar', country: 'USA', age: 99, IQ: 0 },
];

const noIq = data.filter(({ IQ }) => !isNumeric(IQ));
console.log(noIq);

const hasIq = data.filter(({ IQ }) => isNumeric(IQ));
console.log(hasIq);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

A broken example:

```js
const isNumeric = (n) => !isNaN(n - parseFloat(n));

const data = [
  { name: 'Trump', country: 'USA', age: 70, IQ: 150 },
  { name: 'ID Amini', country: 'Uganda', age: 50 },
  { name: 'Kenyatta', country: 'Kenya', age: 60 },
  { name: 'Obama', country: 'USA', age: 45, IQ: 141 },
  { name: 'Foobar', country: 'USA', age: 99, IQ: 0 },
];

const wrong = data.filter(({ IQ }) => !IQ);

console.log(wrong); // Includes 'Foobar'
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: My aim is not only to get  multiple values, I want to be able to get a single object as in my example but not only that but also to be able to get multiple objects if the object does not contain the IQ key. meaning if Item is empty the return multiple objects else return a single object

Answer (score 1):

Various examples using `filter()` and `hasOwnProperty()`

```js
const data = [
    {
        name: 'Trump',
        country: 'USA',
        age: 70,
        IQ: 140,
    },
    {
        name: 'ID Amini',
        country: 'Uganda',
        age: 50,
    },
    {
        name: 'Kenyatta',
        country: 'Kenya',
        age: 60,
        
    },
    {
        name: 'Obama',
        country: 'USA',
        age: 45,
        IQ: 141
        
    }
]


function doFilter(filter, filterTyped) {
  return data.filter(r => {
    if (filter[0] === 'empty') {
      if (!r.hasOwnProperty(filterTyped)) { return r }
    } else {
      if (r.hasOwnProperty(filterTyped) &&  filter.includes(r[filterTyped])) { return r }
    }
  })
}


let filter = ['empty']
let filterTyped ='IQ'
console.log( doFilter(filter, filterTyped) ) // ID Amini and Kenyatta

filter = [141]
filterTyped ='IQ'
console.log( doFilter(filter, filterTyped) ) // Obama

filter = [140, 141]
filterTyped ='IQ'
console.log( doFilter(filter, filterTyped) ) // Trump and Obama
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your snippet, the error is that `forEach` does not return the value. Here is a dummy code, ofc you can make it better.

```
let filter = ['empty']; // passed dynamically u can pass eg Obama, kenyata etc etc
let filterTyped ='IQ' // passed dynamically als here u can pass name, country etc etc

let filteredData = [];
filter.forEach((f) => {
  data.forEach((element) => {
        //return all objects which does not contain IQ if Item is empyt
        if(f === 'empty' && element.IQ === undefined) {
           filteredData.push(element);
        }
    })
})

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: this is bad though

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Trump',
    country: 'USA',
    age: 70,
    IQ: 140,
  },
  {
    name: 'ID Amini',
    country: 'Uganda',
    age: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'Kenyatta',
    country: 'Kenya',
    age: 60,

  },
  {
    name: 'Obama',
    country: 'USA',
    age: 45,
    IQ: 141

  }
]

let noIQ = [];
let hasIQ = [];

for (let key = 0; key < data.length; key++) {
  if (!("IQ" in data[key])) {
    noIQ.push(data[key]);

    // return single object for each entry
    object = Object.assign({}, ...noIQ)
    console.log("object", object)
  }

  if ("IQ" in data[key]) {
    hasIQ.push(data[key])
  }
}

console.log("noIQ:", noIQ)
/* console.log("hasIQ:", hasIQ) */
```